# How to import a C# project to Monodevelop?

Tags: c#, import, monodevelop, raspberry-pi

I write an app in C# on visual studion 2010 under the Windows 7 operating system. But I need to run this app in Monodevelop under the Linux debian operating system installed on Raspberry pi. How can I do this?

Comment: I have already instalded Monodevelop on my Raspberry Pi and I know its possible to run C# apps on it. But I need some information about the method.

Comment: What have you tried? Reading the answers to that question either provide links to blog/documentation and/or commands to execute. Describe in your question which step didn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have no PI ready to go -- but ist should be rather easy. If everything fails - just create a new project in Monodevelop and add your sources manually...
The Xamarin tools could import the sln and proj files directly but they are Windows and MacOS only (I think).